# comparing number to varchar

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a column called `Dept` which is a number and I have another column called `manager` which is a varchar. The `manager` column has a list of numbers in varchar format (1,2,3,4), but also has stores the symbol '%'. My problem is in my query I compare `dept` to `manager`

```
Where dept = [value in manager]
```

If I am comparing `dept` to a `manager` value which is a varchar but contains a number character the query works, but when I compare the `dept` to the `manager` variable and it contains the '%' it does not work anymore.

So to make it clearer I will show some examples

```
Where dept = '1' -OK
Where dept = '2' -OK
Where dept = '%' -NOT OK
```

I tried `to_char(dept)='%'` with no luck. I am not sure what else to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Where dept = '%'` you are trying to find rows where dept is equal to one character: '%'. You should use [Pattern-matching Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52141) and it looks like this `Where dept like '%'`

Answer (score 0):

As `%` is a wildcard-character you must quote it: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm) is a list of all special-characters recognized by oracle and how they can be quoted with braces `{}`.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a wildcard that is why I am using it. When I say dept = '1' that means select dept 1, but I use the % to select where all departments

Comment: I think I found the answer. Is this acceptable or good practice? Instead of dept = '%' I use dept LIKE '%' and it works.

Comment: `%` matches multiple characters and, `_` only one. I basivally thought you tried to match the character itsself...